# how to move files alphabetically using shell

Tags: shell, alphabetical, mv

I have a directory which contains bunch of files. Now I want to move these files to another directory one by one and alphabetically. How can I do this in shell? could mv do this?

Comment: `mv * dest` should work. But how does moving alphabetically make difference?

Comment: @jkshah: it makes difference if the process is aborted for any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glob `*` orders the file names 'alphabetically', so you could use:

```
target="/some/other/directory"
for file in *
do
    mv "$file" "$target"
done
```

It would be quicker to use:

```
mv * "$target"
```

and it does move the files one by one, but it does so in a single invocation of the move command.

Comment: `*` doesn't include files that start with a `'.'`. Could you provide a reference where it promises that the list is sorted? What does "alphabetically" mean in this context, does it take into account the current locale?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I know that `*` doesn't include names that start with dot; the question didn't mention wanting to move such files, and such details would probably confuse the person asking. Likewise, I put 'alphabetically' in quotes to indicate that it more or less works, usually using the current setting of the locale (which is a confounded nuisance on modern systems; I want my files listed in the old order, capitals before lower case, but the modern locales are case-insensitive).  There are lots of caveats that could be added; it will move devices, symlinks, sockets as well as files, etc.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: As for whether it is specified somewhere that files are generated in order, I'm not sure. I didn't find a definitive answer yet in POSIX, though I expect it is there if only you look in the right place.  Empirically, all the mainstream shells have 'always' (since circa 1979, anyway) generated file names in sorted order, so `echo *` echoes the names in a sorted order which is, to a first approximation, alphabetic.  If you want to cavil at more details, write your own answer for others to nitpick at. I guess I should get to bed; I sound grumpy.

Comment: I've found the reference for posix shell in [2.13.3 Patterns Used for Filename Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_03) section: "If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, *sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale*"

Comment: i.e., you can set `LC_COLLATE=C` to get capitals before lower case (ascii order).